# Extract Word Table Into Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error, type-mismatch, word-table

I have a few Word files with the Tables containing Data which I want to export to excel. I've found a script that did it manually. I modified it in the hopes of having it automatically do the same for all files. Each table it finds gets put into a new sheet and then I want it to save with the same File name as the word document. After running the code I get a `Compile Error : Type Mismatch` which points towards `folder = Dir("C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder")`. Here's the code :

```
Option Explicit
Sub AA()
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim WordNotOpen As Boolean
    Dim file As Word.Document
    Dim oTbl As Word.Table
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim folder As Object
   
    ' Prompt for document

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    ' Create new workbook
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Add(Template:=xlWBATWorksheet)
   
    ' Get or start Word
    Set oWord = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set oWord = New Word.Application
        WordNotOpen = True
    End If
   
    'On Error GoTo Err_Handler
   
    ' Open document
    Set folder = Dir("C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder")
    For Each file In folder
    If file.GetExtensionName(file.Path) = "docx" Then
        FilePath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\" & file & ".docx"
        Debug.Print FilePath
        Set file = oWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=FilePath)
        ' Loop through the tables
        For Each oTbl In file.Tables
            ' Create new sheet
            Set wsh = wbk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wbk.Worksheets(wbk.Worksheets.Count))
            ' Copy/paste the table
            oTbl.Range.Copy
            wsh.Paste
        Next oTbl
    
    ' Delete the first sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wbk.Worksheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        wsh.SaveAs Filename:=""
        
    End If
Next
        
'Exit_Handler:
    'On Error Resume Next
   ' oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    'If WordNotOpen Then
    '    oWord.Quit
   ' End If
   ' 'Release object references
   ' Set oTbl = Nothing
    'Set oDoc = Nothing
   ' Set oWord = Nothing
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   ' Exit Sub
   
'Err_Handler:
   ' MsgBox "Word caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
   ' Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `folder` declared and initialised?

Comment: Commenting out the `On Error GoTo Err_Handler` will help you find *where* the issue is - although I suspect @jsheeran has already spotted it.

Comment: The path is already there I just forgot to add it here

Comment: I commented out the Error handlers and I'm getting 'Error 424 Object Required' and it points towards the For Each loop

Comment: Update on everything. I commented out The handlers, Added Option Explicit and created the variables which I had forgotten to do. Now I'm getting "Compile Error: For Each may only iterate over a collection object or an array"

Comment: Please don't post updates in an answer - update your question instead.

Comment: My apologies, done.

Comment: The `Dir` function is used incorrectly -- it returns a `String` with the first file pathname in that folder (unless the folder itself does not exist). Each time you loop, the code will use `Dir` again (without a folder string parameter) which will automatically pull in the next file in the original folder. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382861/4717755) for details.